# How can i get a callback for a long press event performed on button

Tags: iphone, uikit, ios4

I am trying to get some way to get callback on long press event. I don't know if there is any support provided by the IPHONE sdk  for this.

Do i have to design this functionality by my own or is there anything i am missing to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 3.2 and later supports `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` ([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html)).

Comment: how can we accomplish the same in ios < 3.2